# My bulbs are dying before blooming

Tags: diagnosis

I planted tulip. hyacinths, and daffodils bulbs in a 12 ft x 4 ft. garden. I have clay soil. I dug this out 12 in. deep. I replaced the soil with 3 in of garden sand and the rest with cow manure with humus for good drainage. My daffodils didn't come up at all. Some of my tulips bloomed perfect, some came up but died back before blooming and some didn't come up at all. My hyacinths came up and bloomed. Most came up and bloomed then looks like the flowers started to rot. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you dig out the clay? I grow these bulbs in a clay soil, have done for years - the tulips may not come back, but the daffodils not only come back, but increase over the years; hyacinths do their usual, get more like bluebells as the years goes by. What part of the world are you in? and what, precisely, is 'garden sand'? What you've described is trying to grow bulbs without soil in a relatively inhospitable environment

Comment: Do you have pictures you can post?